# Загрузка/удаление записей из базы и вывод в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, entity-framework, mvvm

Есть база данных. Держать все записи в памяти очень ресурсно затратно.
Идея следующая:
Загружать из базы данных 25 записей, которые находятся до текущей записи, и 25, которые находятся после. Как только разница между текущей и последней меньше 10. То удалять 15 первых и загружать 15 дополнительных. Вроде схема алгоритма у меня вышла.

Список загруженных записей я храню в observableCollection, вывожу ее в itemsControl. Рядом с itemsControlom хочу поставить slider, где максимальным значением будет кол-во записей в базе данных.

Но возник вопрос, как передавать изменения из scrollBar, который в itemsControl в мой slider.

Я буду очень рад любой помощи, информации, советам и ссылкам по данной теме.
Возможно есть готовые решения,алгоритмы или библиотеки.
С базой общаюсь используя EntityFramework.

Comment: Может помочь статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/208792/

Comment: @АртемНиколаевич Спасибо, ознакомлюсь!

Comment: [Virtualizing an ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2783845/5045688).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в вашем примере все решилось только XAML разметкой?